# Geoserver - change GeoWebCache Directory

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, tomcat

can you help me please change caching directory of my geoserver instance? I've tried add to web.xml file in Geoserver\WEB-INF this :

```
  <!-- Setting GeoWebCache folder -->
  <context-param>
    <param-name>GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR</param-name>
    <param-value>\data\gwc</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
```

But does not work ...
When I open Tile Layers page in Geoserver Web UI, there are still marked as N/A and when I look at GeoWebCache embedded page I saw my local storage is:

> C:\Users\Denis\AppData\Local\Temp\geowebcache

but in this folder Geoserver does not has permission to read or write, bacause I need my cache folder in geoserver installation folder.

I am using Tomcat 8.5 and Geoserver 2.10 on windows 10. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-8004) in 2.10.1.

Comment: So I can only wait or downgrade?

Comment: or help fix it if you want

Comment: Does the comment by Kevin Smith in thread http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Add-back-the-possibility-to-externalize-GWC-configuration-using-GEOWEBCACHE-CACHE-DIR-td5309333.html mean that users could use GEOWEBCACHE_CONFIG_DIR instead?

Comment: I've no idea, what happens if you try it?